# Is there a quick method to check if a user has access to a specific page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, access

Is there a quick block of a code where given a user ID and a menu item ID, I could quickly check it the user is authorized to open that page?

So far I have this, but it feels like I'm jumping through too many hoops and might be missing something.

```
$access = JFactory::getUser(*id*)->getAuthorisedViewLevels();
$link = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getItem(*id*);
if (in_array($link->access, $access)) {
    // Has access
}
```

I check both the user and menu helpers, and I didn't see anything that looked like it did what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check both the menu exists and if the user has access:

```
use \Joomla\CMS\Factory;

if ($menuItem = Factory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getItem($id))
{
    if (in_array($menuItem->access, Factory::getUser()->getAuthorisedViewLevels()))
    {
        echo "User has access";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "User can NOT access";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Menu item not found"
}
```

Comment: Kind of comes down to a more inline version of what I had. I was hoping there'd be something that didn't call as many resources.